# Why bootstrap CSS is not visible whilst printing through jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a page where I have used Bootstrap and it doesn't include in the print view when I use function like

```
window.print();
```

[image]

I have given a picture to help you understand my problem. I tried to import same bootstrap css file and giving it `media` as `print`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="print">
```

But this doesn't solve problem. Is there any effective solution to print it as original file looks.

Comment: The bootstrap CSS works with media queries...there are media **screen** and **print**, so the ones marked with **screen** won't work even if you force **print** from the link

Comment: The bars aren't visible in print pdf

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has it's own @media print section.

Bootstrap 3.3.7 ([source](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css)) :

```
@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
  abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
  }
  a[href^="#"]:after,
  a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
    content: "";
  }
  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;

    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .btn > .caret,
  .dropup > .btn > .caret {
    border-top-color: #000 !important;
  }
  .label {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
  }
  .table td,
  .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .table-bordered th,
  .table-bordered td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  }
}
```

...

```
@media print {
  .visible-print {
    display: block !important;
  }
  table.visible-print {
    display: table !important;
  }
  tr.visible-print {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-print,
  td.visible-print {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

...

```
@media print {
  .visible-print-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
.visible-print-inline {
  display: none !important;
}
@media print {
  .visible-print-inline {
    display: inline !important;
  }
}
.visible-print-inline-block {
  display: none !important;
}
@media print {
  .visible-print-inline-block {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
@media print {
  .hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

You can

1. Cut this from a bootstrap if you want
2. Write your own css file that will contain your own rules and will override bootstrap rules

Comment: I copied progress bar css and put it in @media print{} but still it didn't show!

Comment: background-color: #337ab7 !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

Comment: Thank you for your concern Alex, can you just write a snipplet for progress bar?

Comment: Please, try this:

@media print { .progress-bar { background-color: #337ab7 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } }

Comment: your custom css file imported before bootstrap.css or later? please, make sure that bootstrap.css imported before custom css